# Undefined variable $ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this error in the browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="make">Make</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="make" id="jozsi">
...
</select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#jozsi').on('change', function(e){
    .....
});
```

And I get error on `#jozsi` variable.

I use Laravel.

Comment: Please import jQuery library into your project, before using jquery!

Comment: Added already,' <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'

Comment: Where do you added this library? before or after your JS code?

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi I putted in layout.blade.php,on the end.

Comment: You should put it before you runany of your jQuery code..!!

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi Solved. Thanks

Comment: Glad to see, it helped  you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include jQuery before running any $ commands.

Your code will be (make sure to first call the jQuery file):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="make">Make</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="make" id="jozsi">
    </select>
</div>


$('#jozsi').on('change', function(e){
    .....
});
```